# 'Scanf' for a String - Program crashing?

Tags: c, string, scanf

Why is this crashing when I input the string? I don't think I'm reading in the string right but the program gives me an error on the first 'scanf.' The program should be correct but this is C not C++. Most help that I could find was for C++.

```
//Andrei Shulgach
//April 27th, 2015
/*A string is a palindrome if it can be read forward and backward with the same 
meaning. Capitalizations and spacing are ignored.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int newStrCmp (const char *string1, const char *string2);

int main()
{
    //Local Declarations
    int dummy, value;
    char string1[100],string2[100];

    printf("Please enter the 1st string: ");
    scanf_s("%99s", string1[100]);
    printf("\nPlease enter the 2nd string: ");
    scanf_s("%99s", string2[100]);

    //Call Function and get value
    value = newStrCmp(string1, string2);

    if (value == 0)
        printf("The strings are equal.\n");
    else
        printf("The strings are not equal.\n");

    scanf_s("%d",&dummy);//Keep Window Open
    return 0;
}

int newStrCmp (const char *string1, const char *string2)
{
    //Local Declarations
    int value = 0;

    while (string1[value] == string2[value]) 
    {
      if (string1[value] == '\0' || string2[value] == '\0')
         break;
         value++;
   }

   if (string1[value] == '\0' && string2[value] == '\0')
      return 0;
   else
      return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must enable all compiler warnings that you can get from your compiler; the above code shouldn't have compiled.

This:

```
scanf_s("%99s", string1[100]);
```

invokes undefined behavior since it indexes *outside* the 100-character `string1` array. Remember that C arrays are indexed from 0. It also fails to comply with `scanf_s()`'s requirement that the size be specified for all string conversions.

It then probably<sup>1</sup> causes *more* undefined behavior, when `scanf_f()` interprets *a single character* as a buffer address where input is to be stored (assuming the call happens, of course).

This is not valid code.

It should simply pass the address of the first character in the array:

```
scanf_s("%99s", string1, sizeof string1);
```

Here, `string1` is the same as `&string1[0]`; the name of an array evaluates to the address of its first element in many contexts. We then use `sizeof string1` as the third argument to specify the size of the `string1` buffer, which is [required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx).

<sup>1</sup> You cannot reason about what happens after undefined behavior has happened with any certainty.

Comment: So what should I do to fix it so it interprets more than a single character?

Comment: This won't work. `scanf_s` requires a third argument denoting the size of the buffer. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx), remarks, 4th paragraph

Comment: @CoolGuy D'oh. Thanks, I'm not overly familiar with the Windows-specific functions. Fixed, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are 'scanf'ing into index 100 of your length 100 buffer, i.e. out-of-bounds.

```
scanf_s("%99s", string1);
```

Also your comparison would be safer as a for loop that ensures value is less than 100, rather than a while loop.
In the future, please include the error message.

Comment: That fix didn't work and the error message is just "The program stopped working..."

Comment: Sorry. Try without the & symbol.